# Error while installing php-pear , dpkg error returned error code 1

Tags: apt, dpkg, php

I was trying to install mongo php driver on ubuntu 14.04 on x64 system.
I used [this tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php/) and when I was trying to install pecl to install the php driver I got an error at the end of the installation.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev php5-cli php-pear
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php-pear is already the newest version.
php5-cli is already the newest version.
php5-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 85 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/etc/environment: line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
```

I tried to check dpkg configuration resulted in the following

```
xxx:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/etc/environment: line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
```

trying to remove the packages is not working even through synaptic package manager

```
xxx:~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge php5-dev php5-cli php-pear
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  php5
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  php-pear* php5-cli* php5-dev* php5-readline* pkg-php-tools*
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php5
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 5 to remove and 85 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,302 B of archives.
After this operation, 15.4 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/etc/environment: line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
```

Contents of install-info

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Wrapper to the GNU's install-info, to be compatible with the one that used to
# be packaged by dpkg on Debian.
#
# written by Norbert Preining, this is not copyrightable ;-)
#
set -e

if [ -z "$DPKG_RUNNING_VERSION" ] ; then
  # it seems we are running from outside a maintainer script, so give a
  # warning and call ginstall-info without anything else
  echo "This is not dpkg install-info anymore, but GNU install-info" >&2
  echo "See the man page for ginstall-info for command line arguments" >&2
  ginstall-info "$@"
else 
  # we are running from a maintainer script, simply ignore the call
  # since we have trigger support and people should rebuild their
  # package with new debhelper which does not add calls to install-info
  # Do not complain if called with "--remove" or "--remove-exactly",
  # as these are used in old packages' prerm scripts (see #546165)
  while [ -n "$1" ]; do
    case "$1" in
      --remove|--remove-exactly)
        exit 0
        ;;
      *)
        shift
        ;;
    esac
  done
  echo "Ignoring install-info called from maintainer script" >&2
  echo "The package $DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE should be rebuilt with new debhelper to get trigger support" >&2
fi
```

Comment: Please post the contents of your `/etc/environment` file. It seems there's a missing " there.

Comment: That's not what I was expecting. Open up your terminal and type `cat /etc/environment` press enter and then copy the result here. Mine is `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"`

Comment: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME = ":usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle

Comment: You don't have a `"` after `java-7-oracle` at the end of your JAVA_HOME path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your /etc/environment is wrong, yours is:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/u‌​sr/local/games" JAVA_HOME = ":usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

while it should look like:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/u‌​sr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle"
```